# Passing several values between two shell scripts

Tags: shell

I have two shell scripts, i.e. (master, function); the master calls the function-script and tries to pass values to it.

Please note that function-script is an interactive script; i.e. it waits for user's answers to perform according to the answer.

So to pass **one** value I can write the following:

```
echo "string" | ./function-script
```

The problem is that I have to pass several values. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the "function-script" operate on positional parameters? If so, you'd call it like:

```
./function-script arg1 "argument 2" arg3
```

And then "function-script" would use `"$1"`, `"$2"` and `"$3"` as required.

If "function-script" only takes input on stdin, do something like this:

```
printf "%s\n" arg1 "argument 2" arg3 | ./function-script
```

And "function-script" would do:

```
IFS= read -r arg1
IFS= read -r arg2
IFS= read -r arg3
```

Comment: Actually I need the second case. I face a problem with the flag -r -r: command not found
Indeed the manuals for read do not include the flag -r as far as I read. so could you please explain a little more

Comment: show the exact code that produced that error. What shell are you using?

Comment: I use bash shell on debian 2.30.2 and on ubuntu 14.04.1
However, here are my test scripts:
master.sh:
`printf "%s\n" "1" "2" | ./func.sh`

func.sh:
`echo "enter 2 numbers:"
first=read -r arg1
second=read -r arg2
echo "================="
echo $first
echo $second`

and sorry because of the formatting of the code part in the comment..

Comment: 1. the way to capture the output of a command is with `$()`, so `output=$(command)`. 2. Just use the varname you want in the read command `read -r first; read -r second`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

- Don't try to pass multiple variable.
- Just export all the variable within master script using `export a=1` syntax.
- Then call child script from master like a regular script
- All the variable will be available in child script.

Answer (score 0):

Use command line arguments.

```
./function-script "string" "another string"
```

If you pre-empt standard input by piping data into the function script, you make interactive operation of the function script hard.

You could instead export the variables as environment variables, but just as global variables in regular programming are not a good idea because their use is hidden, so too with environment variables.